# Tried "everything". My menu keeps going behind my featured slider in IE6. (CSS z-index?)

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

Tried everything, my dropdown menu keeps going behind my slider in IE6. See here:

http://www.vectorsig.com

View it in IE6, and the menu goes behind the slider. (That's a mock-up site for testing purposes, nothing important on there.)

I tried putting the slider at z-index: -1, position: relative...nothing, tried fiddling with the menu. Nothing.

I'm at the point where I'm just sitting here, smashing keys, staring at the screen. ANY help would be much appreciated.

---

Here is some background info: 
It's running on wordpress, with the theme: News. (http://devpress.com/themes/news/)

The slider is "Simple Nivo Slider", a WP plugin: (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-nivo-slider/ )

***EDIT: SOLVED (the forum wouldn't let me Answer my own post.***

I used this.

```
.menu{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

#container{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: FYI, IE7 has the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

So I notice that the anchor tags in your slider have positive z-index values (5, 6, 8, etc.). Have you tried giving your menu elements a generously *high* z-index? Also, just a shot in the dark here, you might try giving both your menu and your slider elements `zoom: 1`. This won't affect the magnification of your elements, but it will give them the `hasLayout` property, which has been known to fix little quirks like these in IE.

Comment: SOLVED IT. See above. (Couldn't answer my own question b/c my repuation was too low (need 1000+??)).

Answer (score 0):

I would't use negative z-index in any circumstance. It will prevent some events from being fired on the element. Always use positive z-index for the element which needs to be in front.

Answer (score 0):

check adding this at the top of your header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

otherwise try adding this one in your header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```